# UIImageView Takes Time To Load Image

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, nsurlconnection, nsoperationqueue, nsinvocationoperation

I wanted to download image from internet from particular link
Downloading this image take place in other class which is Singleton class name moreAppInternet.m

My moreAppInterNet.m file is as follow

```
//finishedImgDling is bool

//mutableData is NSMutableData

//urlConnection is NSURLConnection

//appimage is UIImage

//imageUrl is NSString Containing Link

 +(id)sharedManager
{

    static moreAppInterNet *sharedMyManager = nil;

    @synchronized(self) {

        if (sharedMyManager == nil)

            sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    }

    return sharedMyManager;
}


-(void)downloadImageFromUrl
{    
    finishedImgDling = NO;
        
    [self.mutableData setLength:0];
    
    self.urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageUrl]] delegate:self];
    
    
    while(!finishedImgDling) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }   
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

    if (connection == self.urlConnection)
    {

        NSLog(@"imageDling");
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    if (connection == self.urlConnection)
    {

        if (self.mutableData == nil)
        {
            self.mutableData = [NSMutableData data];
        }
                
        [self.mutableData appendData:data];
    }
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    if (connection == self.urlConnection)
    {
        NSLog(@"image Downloaded");
        
        finishedImgDling = YES;
                
        [self setUrlConnection:nil];
        
        [self storeImage];
    }
}

-(void)storeImage
{

    [self setAppimage:nil];
    
    self.appimage = [UIImage imageWithData:self.mutableData];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];     
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    
    NSString *path =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"appImage.png"]];
          
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:path contents:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.appimage) attributes:nil];

     NSLog(@"downloading and storing complete");
        
}

and my other ViewController is as follow from where I call that function


-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    [moreAppInterNet sharedManager];

    [self downloadImage];
}

-(void)downloadImage
{

     NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(download_Image_from_other_class) object:nil];
        
    NSOperationQueue *que = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    
    [que addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"operations" options:0 context:NULL];
    
    [que addOperation:operation];
    
    [operation release];
    
    self.dlingQue = que;
    
    [que release];
}

-(void)download_Image_from_other_class
{

    [[moreAppInterNet sharedManager] downloadImageFromUrl];
}

-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                         change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"operations"] && object == self.dlingQue)
    {

        if ([self.dlingQue operationCount] == 0)
        {

            self.imgView = [[moreAppInterNet sharedManager] appimage];

            //it takes lots of time to display image in UIImageView
            //Even though Above line get executed
        }
    }
    else {

        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object
                               change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

The Problem is that `self.imgView` takes Lots of time to load the image approx. 5sec even though its downloaded completely.

Answer (score 1):

The library I use for networking is [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code downloads the image again when you request it.

You need to check if you have the file in `downloadImageFromUrl`.

Probably, you need more robust library to handle file downloading.

Comment: actually i am downloading form different links..
so evrytime it will download new image